# How to solve stackoverflow errors in servlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have declared all of my variables and methods in public inside the (servletconn.java). i want to access that variables and methods from another one servlet(NewServlet.java), am creating an object using **conn co=new conn();** .but that code displays an error            **(stackoverflow Error)**. how do i solve this problem?

Comment: The amount of detail you provide makes it impossible to answer this question in a meaningful way. Stackoverflow is usually caused by unbounded recursion, but we'd need more of your code to make this analysis.

Comment: The stacktrace alone is also enough (the duplicated parts omitted).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're recursivelly calling your servlets. Without some code, it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a servlet throws IOException,ServletException by default in the callback methods like doGet,doPost etc.

Creating a Database Connection also needs to throw SQLException, ClassNotFoundException Just try to catch these instead of throwing them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share information between servlets, Why not use [`ServletContext`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html)? You can use `ServletContext.setAttribute(key, object)` (for uploading) and `ServletContext.getAttribute(key)` for retrieval.

There is 1 `ServletContext` per web application, per JVM. So, each servlet, in your webapp, have the same `ServletContext`.